# Wordpress $post->ID

Tags: wordpress, post

Is it possible to use a custom `ID` in the loop? For example use `$post->122334535` instead of `$post->ID.`

Th thing is. I have custom posts, attached to those custom posts are *images*. I need the images for another page created bij *CakePHP* instad of *Wordpress.*

The pages have the same `ID`'s so I tried it like this:
 `<?php get_post_meta($post->$info['id'], 'Thumbnail') ?>`
But no response. The `ID` and `$info['id']` are the same number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting it wrong. If, for whatever reason you want to use your own ID, you should replace the whole `$post->ID` by the ID you want.

For example, if you want to use post ID `123`, you must use:

```
<?php
echo get_post_meta(123, 'Thumbnail'); 
?>
```

Note that I've added an `echo` because using only `get_post_meta` won't print anything, it just returns a value.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Guess I was confused by the use of ID in $post->ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use like `$post->122334535` instead of `$post->ID`. Because wordpress post query gives the post ID by writing the code `$post->ID`. Together `Post` and `->ID` echo the id of the post in wordpress. SO you can use `122334535`(which is `post_id`) instead of `Post->ID`.